# Selenium Java automation with Browserstack automate, when trying to test with international languages like Korean it converts the character on BS

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

When we try and enter below text on web via browserstack it converts the characters:

```
"chineseSampleQuery": "我想为我的儿子购买平板电脑",
"koreanSampleQuery": "아들을 위해 태블릿을 사고 싶어요",
"arabicSampleQuery": "أريد أن أشتري لوحاً لابني",
```

E.g:
when entered "Ä ä Ö ö Ü ü ẞ ß" it converts as "Ã„ Ã¤ Ã– Ã¶ Ãœ Ã¼ áºž ÃŸ" while entering to input filed.
I've tried 2 ways:

any suggestion how to achieve this?
Screenshot of how it's converted'Ä ä Ö ö Ü ü ẞ ß'(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBUb7.png)

1.

```java
String text = "이 사이트에서 태블릿을 구입할 수 있습니까?";
byte[] utf8Bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Replace with the appropriate encoding

driver.findElement(By.id("yourInputField")).sendKeys(new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

2. 

```java
String koreanText = "\uC774 \uC0AC\uC774\uD2B8\uC5D0\uC11C \uD0C0\uC785\uB9CC \uAD6C\uC785\uD558\uC9C0 \uC54A\uC2B5\uB2C8\uB2E4?";
```

Both did not work.

Comment: Hi there, Could you Add the IDE specs as well as the Selenium version you are using? Also, is this occurring only on some browser+OS combination?

Comment: Hello , Using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition), Selenium-v4.8.1 and   there are multiple browsers used for this testing. 1. "browserName": "Chrome","deviceName": "OnePlus 9","osVersion": "11.0",  2. "browserName" :"Chrome","browserVersion" : "114","os": "windows",   3. "browserName": "Safari","deviceName": "iPhone 14","osVersion": "16.3". Also Firefox, edge safari browsers. On all I'm facing this issue.